# I need a countdown timer in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to display a countdown timer that shows how many minutes and hours it will be until a shipping and processing deadline is hit to have a products delivered (and also display the estimated delivery based off of that).

I'm really new to JS/jQuery and know this can be done in PHP, but I'm injecting JS through a 3rd party tool to help me test, so it has to be JS. Really looking for any help I can get, and I've also been looking into moment.js.

Comment: 1. Do some basic JS tutorials to become acquainted with the language. 2. Learn about setInterval and setTimeout. 3. Learn about the Date object. 4. Put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a ready made stuff you can learn from?

```
class Clock {
  constructor(date = new Date(), deadline = false) {
    this.date = date;
    this.deadline = deadline;
  }
  start() {
   let interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.date = new Date(this.date.getTime() - 1000);
    if(this.date === this.deadline) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }
    const zeroIt = (...dateArray) => {
      return dateArray.map((date) => {
        return date < 10 ? '0' + date : date;
      });
    };

    var dateArray = zeroIt(this.date.getHours(), this.date.getMinutes(),this.date.getSeconds());

     document.body.innerHTML = dateArray.join(' : ');
  },1000);
 }

}

const clock = new Clock();
clock.start();
```

Improve for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this famous jQuery plugin from here: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

For this you need Jquery v2.0.1 as mentioned here, http://plugins.jquery.com/kbw.countdown/

All you need to do is include download the files and include the js and css file and follow the steps given in the site and you are good to go.